# how can i customise the width of the cell which are the part of uitableview(grouped) in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How can I customise the width of cells that are the part of a uitableview(grouped) in iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

```
CGRect frame = cell.frame;
frame.size.width = 123f;
cell.frame = frame;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't, all you can do is resizing the table view and adding it as a subview to a view